# Detect code for GeSHi

Tags: php, text, blogs, geshi

I'm making a blog from scratch in PHP + MySQL, where I will sometimes post lines of PHP codes for tutorials and so on... So, I installed the GeSHi class in my project.
But since I will write my blogs/articles in normal text format, I will write up some tutorials like:

> ```
> Here is some PHP code:
> [code=php]
> <?php
> echo 'Hello World!';
> ?>
> [/code]
> ```

And this will be stored on my MySQL DB in TEXT format, so how can I set PHP to recognize code's and use the GeSHi class to parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can do that by simple [regular replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
function code($match) {
    $geshi = new GeSHi($match[2], $match[1]);
    return $geshi->parse_code();
}
$html = preg_replace_callback('~\[code=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/code\]~is', 'code', $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways :

## Simplest but worse :

```
preg_replace_callback('#\[code=([a-zA-Z]+)](.+)\[/code]#sU',function($matches){
    $geshi = new GeShi($matches[1]);
     return $geshi->parse($matches[2]);
    },
 $text    );
```

## Little Harder but quite efficient and addaptive :

http://php.net/manual/fr/book.bbcode.php

```
$bbcodeContainer = bbcode_create(array(
''=>         array('type'=>BBCODE_TYPE_ROOT,  'childs'=>'!i'),
'i'=>        array('type'=>BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG, 'open_tag'=>'<i>',
                'close_tag'=>'</i>', 'childs'=>'b'),
'url'=>      array('type'=>BBCODE_TYPE_OPTARG,
                'open_tag'=>'<a href="{PARAM}">', 'close_tag'=>'</a>',
                'default_arg'=>'{CONTENT}',
                'childs'=>'b,i'),
'img'=>      array('type'=>BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG,
                'open_tag'=>'<img src="', 'close_tag'=>'" />',
                'childs'=>''),
'b'=>        array('type'=>BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG, 'open_tag'=>'<b>',
                'close_tag'=>'</b>'),
 ));

bbcode_add_element($bbcodeContainer,'code',array('type'=>BBCODE_TYPE_OPTARG,
         'open_tag'=>'<div class="code">','close_tag'=>'</div>',
         'content_handling'=>function($content,$params){
                $geshi = new GeShi($params[0]);
                return $geshi->parse($content);   
            }));
```